# Show link in html table cell

Tags: html

I'm tring to add a link in my code like below,I have written a javascript function,thing is in UI it has to show data as link.

string str="" + dataTable.Rows[i][j] + ""

Is there a way to show my datatable data as a link in UI?
Reply

Comment: Your example is not correctly formed. There's no inner <a> element to match the </a>. Also, what exactly is the problem, please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that your dataTable[i][j] is the link .. we can simply do this in javascript to create a link

```
link = '<a href="' + dataTable[i][j] + '" >Link</a>';
```

then use this string wherever you want.

or as i just saw the updated question

```
'<td><a href="#" onclick="goToFunction()">' + dataTable[i][j] + '</a></td>'
```

Comment: :Thanks for the reply,why to use ne more variabe here,Can`t I use like,<td onClick='GoToFunction()'><a href='" + dataTable.Rows[i][j] + "'</a></td>...I tried this didn`t work.

Comment: Yeah this works well,I didn`t know that we can call funcitons from anchor tag.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where is the start of the anchor (<a ...>) tag?  There is only an end one.  Try...

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="GoToFunction()">{link}</a></td>
```